# Override ResourceHttpRequestHandler Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to override ResourceHttpRequestHandler in my Spring MVC application.

I have the following class so far:

```
@Controller
public class ResourceHttpRequestHandlerReplacer extends ResourceHttpRequestHandler implements BeanFactoryPostProcessor {

@Override
public void handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    super.handleRequest(request, response);
}

public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory factory)
        throws BeansException {
    String[] names = factory.getBeanNamesForType(ResourceHttpRequestHandler.class);

    for (String name : names) {
        BeanDefinition bd = factory.getBeanDefinition(name);
        bd.setBeanClassName("com.project.controllers.ResourceHttpRequestHandlerReplacer");
    }
}

}
```

Right now its supposed to just call the super handleRequest so nothing should have changed but I am getting this message:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: WebApplicationObjectSupport instance [ResourceHttpRequestHandler [locations=[], resolvers=[org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.PathResourceResolver@16943e88]]] does not run within a ServletContext. Make sure the object is fully configured!

I am trying to override so that I can implement some custom logic around trying to find resources that aren't static but aren't mapped by a controller either as the user will be able to define URLs for the pages in their CMS.

Can anyone advise where ive gone wrong?

Thanks

Comment: You should split your own handler and the logic replacing it. Move the logic for the `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` to a separate class instead of in the same class. These `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` run very early in the proces, before anything has been set, however due to the extension it still requires a `ServletContext`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

looks like your `ResourceHttpRequestHandlerReplacer` is not aware of the servletContext, which is rare since you are extending it from `ResourceHttpRequestHandler`. Try adding this to your class

```
@Autowired
ServletContext servletContext;
```